# How to split the string in java based ',' as a delimeter

Tags: java

I have the following string, and want to split exactly on 16th position, it should not split when there is word in between 16th position

**String input = "ARAPAHOE (CO), test"**

**The out put should be as follows:**
  **ARAPAHOE (CO)

  test**

I already tried with the following code:

```
        Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("(.{1,16})\\b(,|$)");
        Matcher m = splitPattern.matcher("ARAPAHOE (CO), test");
        List<String> splittedComList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) {
            splittedComList.add(m.group(1));
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Show us your code :)

Comment: The title and body text are contradicting. Do you want to split based on position, or based on delimiter? What should be the output if the 16th position is inside a word?

Comment: So you just want to spit if 16th character is a space?

Comment: in the above example if i split at 16th position i would get out put as follows:         "ARAPAHOE (CO), t"  and "esu" as other one. It should not be split like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `input.split(',')`

Or maybe I don't understand the question .. tell me :p